# Source R file in reactive context (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

Beginner Shiny question.

I have two models living in different folders, `A` and `B`, both called `inputs.R`, and want to load one or the other using `selectInput` to choose the folder (in reality, there is more than one file in each folder, so I don't want to load the file directly).

Currently, I have

```
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("model_folder", "Select folder", c("A", "B")))

server <- function(input, output){
    reactive({
    inpts <- paste0("models/",input$model_folder, "/inputs.R") 
    source(inpts, local = T)
    })
}
```

This does not work. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to happen when you are sourcing the `inpts`?  Are you just trying to store a model into a variable (ie the result of an `lm` or some such)?

Comment: There are several functions in `inputs.R` (which will have different functionality between folders A and B) that I want to make available to the session.

Comment: It would be better to make a more complete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What does "does not work" mean exactly here? Are you getting an error or just not the behavior you expected? If the latter, what is the behavior you expected?

Comment: @MrFlick - I expected this to make the functions in `inputs.R` available inside the function, but this is not the case. I presume, in line what @bunk's comment, that reactive returns a value; I was thinking that it was more akin to an `if()` statement? Thanks both of you, I'll experiment and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend where you have your 'models' folder stored.  So, pretend it is in the same directory as your shiny app.  Here is some code that should recreate this situation, along with some models and data in the two separate folders.  Just change the variable `appDir` to wherever you don't have a folder.

```
## Create the models/folders in a temporary location
## define it in appDir
appDir <- 'c:/path/to/temp/app'
dir.create(appDir)
dir.create(file.path(appDir, "models"))
for (i in 1:2) {
    dir.create((folder = file.path(appDir, "models/", LETTERS[i])))
    code <- bquote({
        dat <- data.frame((x=rnorm(100)), y=rnorm(100, mean=.(i)*x))
        mod <- lm(y ~ x, data=dat)
    })
    writeLines(deparse(code), file.path(folder, 'input.R'))
}
```

Then, in the new folder `appDir`, create a file `app.R`, which will be the example application.  There are problems with how you are trying to use `reactive`, illustrated below.  I capture all the variables from the sourced `input.R` files using `mget()` in this example.

```
library(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        selectInput("model_folder", "Select folder", c("A", "B")),
        uiOutput('info'),
        tableOutput('summ')
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$info <- renderUI({
            inp <- inpts()
            list(
                helpText(sprintf("Now looking at variables from %s", inp$name)),
                radioButtons('vars', 'Variables', choices=names(inp), inline=TRUE)
            )
        })

        output$summ <- renderTable({
            inp <- inpts()
            if (input$vars == 'mod') summary(inp$mod)
        })

        inpts <- reactive({
            name <- file.path("models", input$model_folder, "input.R")
            source(name, local=TRUE)
            mget(ls())
        })
    }
)
```

Now, to run it you can just do

```
library(shiny)
runApp(appDir = normalizePath(appDir))
```

Comment: Very neat indeed! Thanks a thousand.

Comment: Worked! You little ripper!